# How to create an admin login and dashboard using Laravel Livewire?

Tags: php, admin, laravel-livewire

I'm using creating a project and I need to add to that project an admin panel, which is the login form(for the admin to login) in `admin/login` and the admin dashboard as well. I'm using Laravel 8 for this project and I wanted to create the admin panel using Livewire.
Any idea how to start it, or any suggested tutorial where I can follow it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jetstream - another package for Laravel 8 which gives you login, registration, session and two factor authentication and much more. You just have to change some HTML tags.

Installing jetstream:

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

If you use livewire and install jetstream with livewire then you can use

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire
```

Here is the link of YouTube video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz_YkiqIHesvPtvLl2Wz5FtuW44dBt199
```